# Complex linq join in EF6

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

There are two entities, for example, **job** and **solution**.
Each of them has a **date** field and a **level** field and a **quantity** field.

It is necessary to combine them so that they are grouped first by level, then by month, and at the same time, their quantity must be summed up.

I tried different options, but nothing comes out at all. The main problem is grouping by *months* and summing the numbers in the enclosed sheets.

That is, the output should be one sequence of summed numbers, grouped by level, and then by month.

For example:

```cs
var jobs = new List<Job>()
{
new Job { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), Quantity = 111 },
new Job { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 20), Quantity = 222 },
new Job { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 1), Quantity = 333 },
new Job { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 20), Quantity = 444 }
};

var solutions = new List<Solution>()
{
new Solution { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 1), Quantity = 555 },
new Solution { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 20), Quantity = 666 },
new Solution { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), Quantity = 777 },
new Solution { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 20), Quantity = 888 }
};
```

Output:

- Level 1 -> 1 Jan 2019 -> 1110 (111 + 222 + 777)
- Level 1 -> 1 Feb 2019 -> 555
- Level 2 -> 1 Jan 2019 -> 888
- Level 2 -> 1 Feb 2019 -> 1443 (333 + 444 + 666)

And so on. And yes, all this is in EF6.

Comment: Post some code in order to understand what you have tried so far so others can help you with your code and understand what is wrong with it

Comment: Please at least post the data structure and more real inputs and outputs. Is `2/1/2018` February 1 or January 2? Add a list with the inputs and comment on the output expected

Comment: Maybe something like this example can help you: var aList = jobs.Select(x => new Tuple<int, DateTime, int>(x.Level, x.Date, x.Quantity));
            var bList = solutions.Select(x => new Tuple<int, DateTime, int>(x.Level, x.Date, x.Quantity));
            var groupedList = aList.Union(bList).GroupBy(x => new { x.Item2, x.Item1 }).Select(x => new { Date = x.Key.Item2, Sum = x.Sum(y => y.Item3) });
            var orderedList = groupedList.OrderBy(x => x.Date);

Answer (score 1):

Try following which uses Concat.  I create a class for the merging.  It can also be done anonymously.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication116
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jobs = new List<Job>()
            {
                new Job { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), Quantity = 111 },
                new Job { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 20), Quantity = 222 },
                new Job { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 1), Quantity = 333 },
                new Job { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 20), Quantity = 444 }
            };

            var solutions = new List<Solution>()
            {
                new Solution { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 1), Quantity = 555 },
                new Solution { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 20), Quantity = 666 },
                new Solution { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), Quantity = 777 },
                new Solution { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 20), Quantity = 888 }
            };


            List<LevelDateQuantity> concat = jobs.Select(x => new LevelDateQuantity() { Date = x.Date, Level = x.Level, Quantity = x.Quantity})
                .Concat( solutions.Select(x => new LevelDateQuantity() { Date = x.Date, Level = x.Level, Quantity = x.Quantity})).ToList();

            List<LevelDateQuantity> results = concat.OrderBy(x => x.Level).ThenBy(x => x.Date)
                .GroupBy(x => new { level = x.Level, date = new DateTime(x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month,1)})
                .Select(x => new LevelDateQuantity() { Level = x.Key.level, Date = x.Key.date, Quantity = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity)})
                .ToList();
        }

    }
    public class LevelDateQuantity
    {
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
    public class Job : LevelDateQuantity
    {
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
    public class Solution : LevelDateQuantity
    {
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oath, because we can not see your poco class structure we don't know if the two tables are seperate or has a one to many relation to a master table, so by the code you have provided I would do this ;

```
var jobs = new List<Job>()
{
new Job { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), Quantity = 111 },
new Job { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 20), Quantity = 222 },
new Job { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 1), Quantity = 333 },
new Job { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 20), Quantity = 444 }
};

var solutions = new List<Solution>()
{
new Solution { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 1), Quantity = 555 },
new Solution { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 2, 20), Quantity = 666 },
new Solution { Level = 1, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), Quantity = 777 },
new Solution { Level = 2, Date = new DateTime(2019, 1, 20), Quantity = 888 }
};


foreach (var sol in solutions)
{
  var jb = new Job();
  jb.Level = sol.Level;
  jb.Date = sol.Date ;
  jb.Quantity= sol.Quantity;

   jobs.Add(jb);
}

 var result = Jobs.GroupBy(x=> new { x.Level, x.Date}).Select(x=> new 
 {
  level = x.Key.Level,
  date = x.Key.Date,
  sumQ = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity )
 });
```

I haven't tested the code and not wrote in in a compiler so there might be some typeerrors apart from that this should solve your problem.